# How insert three or more table sql from raw to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have three sql table and I intend to insutk insertk into sqlite database, the program I run is still error, anyone know for this solution?

> this code work in android version 4 and 7 but error in 5 and 6

**AsyncTask in Myactivity.class**

```
 private void initData() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    new doBackground().execute();
}

class doBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Menunggu beberapa detik");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Memasang Database");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        insertFromFile(MainActivity.this, R.raw.quran);
        insertFromFile(MainActivity.this, R.raw.quran_indo);
        insertFromFile(MainActivity.this, R.raw.quran_trans);
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

public void insertFromFile(Context context, int resourceId) {
    try {
        InputStream insertsStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        BufferedReader insertReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(insertsStream));

        database.beginTransaction();

        while (insertReader.ready()) {
            String insertStmt = insertReader.readLine();
            database.execSQL(insertStmt);
        }

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();

        insertReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static String NAMA_DATABASE = "myalqurana";
static String NAMA_TABEL_ARAB = "Quran";
static String NAMA_TABEL_INDO = "QuranIndo";
static String NAMA_TABEL_TRANS = "Quran_trans";
static String ID = "ID";
static String DatabaseID = "DatabaseID";
static String SuraID = "SuratID";
static String VerseID = "VerseID";
static String AyatText = "AyatText";
static int VERSI_DATABASE = 2;
Context pesan;

String sql_create_arab = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ NAMA_TABEL_ARAB +" (" +
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        DatabaseID + " SMALLINT NOT NULL, " +
        SuraID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        VerseID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        AyatText + " TEXT CHARACTER" +
        "); ";
String sql_create_indo = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ NAMA_TABEL_INDO +" (" +
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        DatabaseID + " SMALLINT NOT NULL, " +
        SuraID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        VerseID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        AyatText + " TEXT CHARACTER " +
        "); ";
String sql_create_trans = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAMA_TABEL_TRANS +" (" +
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        DatabaseID + " SMALLINT NOT NULL, " +
        SuraID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        VerseID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        AyatText + " TEXT CHARACTER " +
        "); ";
String sql_drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAMA_TABEL_ARAB;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NAMA_DATABASE, null, VERSI_DATABASE);
    this.pesan = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sql_create_arab);
    db.execSQL(sql_create_indo);
    db.execSQL(sql_create_trans);
}


}
```

---

***Log chat error***

FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                             Process: com.ideabrains.alquranindonesia, PID: 5278 
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: Do you have three _databases_ or three _tables_?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
I have three different tables

Comment: static String NAMA_DATABASE = "myalqurana.sqlite" or "myalqurana.db"

Comment: You can just store resource name or I'd, instead of storing full raw file.

Comment: @G.Dator 
No effect, this runs smoothly on android version 4 and 7 but errors in android version 5 and 6

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Sorry I do not understand with this

Comment: You are trying to save **R.raw.quran** and some other raw file in your database as BLOB, but actually, these files are available in your app only, You can just save the reference by name or unique ids in the database and you can get back when ever you need us the reference name.